# Sitecore 8.2 Performance issue / crash

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore8.2

Right so after upgrading to Sitecore 8.2 from 8.1 with split environment i.e CD and CMS. I'm seeing few performance issues, The CMS works fine but the number of threads is around 200 in local! whereas CD just freezes by just consuming all the memory just after starting the site, there no error shown in the log as well.

Any idea what might be wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason may be the size of the Sitecore event queue.

Check the record count from all the Event queues especially the web database:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM [EventQueue]
```

If the count is high like 100K you need to clean up for better performance. Work best when there are at most a few thousand records.

See:

[Publish Queue, History and Event Queue too big](https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/1450)

[sitecore-event-queue-how-to-clean-it-and-why](https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2016/08/12/sitecore-event-queue-how-to-clean-it-and-why/)

Comment: the event queues are very stable, but the number of threads stays around 177 on local machine also dont see any error in log

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you are not getting any error continuously in log files on CD server.

Check for redirects if you have and see if they are causing problems. We found this one as an issue in our instance in the past.

You can watch for Sitecore performance counter for more diagnosis.

Comment: log seems to be stable dont see any exception or error

Answer (score 0):

For CPU high usage process, i think you need to stop some agent processes which considered one of the memory consuming process, try Stop this cleanup agent in sitecore.config file be set the interval to **zero**

```
<agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.CleanupAgent" method="Run" interval="06:00:00">
```

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue where the CPU usage was spiking but could not find any error in sitecore log files.Also the web traffic was normal as observed from the IIS logs. This is how we resolved the issue.

In IIS user interface and in the application pool where the site is hosted,please check the currently running IIS worker Processes.Here we can see that each request is in different part of ASP.NET pipeline and currently executing HTTP modules.

Now please check whether any requests are getting stuck at any stage.If there are multiple requests coming from the same URL are getting stuck then it means that some module in that URL is getting hung up or going into an infinite loop.Now we can investigate the modules used in this URL and find the actual issue.